# Convert list of one type to list of another type in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I have an object, with ID and Name properties.

I have a list of the objects, but I want to convert it to a list of strings containing the name of the object.
I'm guessing there's some fancy Linq method that will put the name of the object into the list.

```
List<string> myObjectNames = myObjectList.?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you know it is specifically a `List<T>` and not another collection type then you can use [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx):

> Converts the elements in the current `List<T>` to another type, and returns a list containing the converted elements.

Example:

```
List<string> myObjectNames = myObjectList.ConvertAll(x => x.Name);
```

---

If you just know that it is an enumerable type but not necessarily a list then you can use the LINQ extension methods [`Enumerable<T>.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) and [`Enumerable<T>.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
List<string> myObjectNames = myObjects.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: You probably ought to mention the Cast extension method?

Comment: The Cast<T>() extension method does the thing written in the questions title (like converting a list of strings to a list of integers). But it does not fit the example in the question...