# LINQ: How to convert query results during select?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, type-conversion

This returns a list of `strings`:

```
var filesizes = from fd in files
                from tag in fd.Tags
                where tag.Id == ID.FILESIZE
                select tag.Value;
```

The following doesn't work, but is there maybe a way to do something similar to convert `string` to `int` during the query?

```
var filesizes = from fd in files
                from tag in fd.Tags
                where tag.Id == ID.FILESIZE
                select new { int.Parse(tag.Value) };
```

Or should I just use [ConvertAll as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555661/convert-list-of-one-type-to-list-of-another-type-in-c-3-5)?

Comment: would it work if you dropped `new {`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can either do:

```
var filesizes = from fd in files
                from tag in fd.Tags
                where tag.Id == ID.FILESIZE
                select new { FileSize = int.Parse(tag.Value) };
```

or

```
var filesizes = from fd in files
                from tag in fd.Tags
                where tag.Id == ID.FILESIZE
                select int.Parse(tag.Value);
```

Comment: Chosen for showing multiple possibilities. I'm sure the first variation will come in handy soon as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can just put `select int.Parse(tag)` at the end instead of `select tag.Value`:

```
var filesizes = from fd in files
                from tag in fd.Tags
                where tag.Id == ID.FILESIZE
                select int.Parse(tag.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to wrap integer with new { ... } ? It is simple:

```
var filesizes = from fd in files
                from tag in fd.Tags
                where tag.Id == ID.FILESIZE
                select int.Parse(tag.Value);
```

Comment: I don't (yet). It just didn't occur to me at the time to try without.