# How to create a collection while doing a for each in a short cut way or probably a new way?

Tags: c#

So if I have a collection of animals and I want to use some properties into a new object like so:

```
class Animal{
public string Name {get; set;}
public string TypeOfAnimal {get; set;}
public short Weight {get; set;}
public string Color {get; set;}
}

class Zoo{
 public string AnimalType {get; set;}
 public bool ForAdoption {get; set;}
 public decimal ApproximateWeight {get; set;}
}

var listOfAnimals = List<Animal>();
var myAnimalsCollection = GetAllAnimalsFromDB();

foreach (var animalItem in myAnimalsCollection)
{
   var zooObject= new Zoo {
     Animaltype = animalItem.TypeOfAnimal,
     ApproximateWeight = animalItem.Weight,
     ForAdoption = false
    };

   listOfAnimals.Add(zooObject);
}
```

Like initializing a collection then adding them one by one after creating a new object. I was wondering if there is a common way now in C# to simplify the code?

Comment: ```zooObject``` is ```Zoo``` class but ```listOfAnimals``` is ```List<Animal>```. There's no inheritance relationship and I don't think you can add ```zooObject``` to ```listOfAnimals```. Also, is ```myAnimalsCollection``` collection of ```Animal```?

Comment: @MarkSouls sorry about that, you are right. I made a mistake, that collection should be var listOfAnimals = List<Zoo>();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of one type to list of another type in C# 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555661/convert-list-of-one-type-to-list-of-another-type-in-c-sharp-3-5)

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's additional learning info for me. But for this question, Nirav's reply is I believe the one I'm after. cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ in c#. I have also resolved some issue in your given question.

```
class Zoo
{
   public string AnimalType { get; set; }
   public bool ForAdoption { get; set; }
   public decimal ApproximateWeight { get; set; }
}

class Animal
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string TypeOfAnimal { get; set; }
  public short Weight { get; set; }
  public string Color { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myAnimalsCollection = GetAllAnimalsFromDB();

        var listOfAnimals = (from item in myAnimalsCollection
                             select new Zoo
                             {
                                 AnimalType = item.TypeOfAnimal,
                                 ApproximateWeight = item.Weight,
                                 ForAdoption = false
                             }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. Is this now the preferred syntax and not the itemized creation of object and then being added to collection one by one? Is this how it's done in most production code? Thanks

Comment: @LailaVilla For simple projections like this, yes. You can use it for a bunch of cases, but there are still times when you'll want to do a `foreach` instead. Sometimes the LINQ solution is less efficient or more complex than the equivalent `foreach`.

Comment: I agree with @Corey